# Can WampServer be used successfully in production?

Tags: networking, wamp, wampserver

Can WampServer be used successfully in production? Is this a bad idea?

So everyone knows, and I don't see how this mattered, we've paid for a windows dedicated box and we have existing IIS apps. We just wanted to use a PHP based CMS which installs easier on apache (since it has some dependencies). So, as the title indicated, windows, apache, php, and mysql are requirements.

Additionally, I'm talking specifically of the WampServer flavor of WAMP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're not going onto the internet, there isn't any reason really not to.  Of course you'd have to look at all the normal caveats - backups etc.

Instead of using an already made one, why not try to do your own?  It would be a good learning experience and really they aren't that hard to get working together.

Comment: Did it manually. Wasn't too bad. Took me about 3.5 hours and I'm much more comfortable with each component and their interactivity now.

Answer (score 2):

WAMP is approriate for production of an Intranet.  We developed a solution with FLEX  (front END) /PHP/MYSQL  (BACKEND) and it's been working very well for a year now.   You just have to secure the Server on which WAMP runs.  WAMP is just a tool for configuring APACHE/PHP/MYSQL on a Windows plateform with ease.

Answer (score 1):

WampServer themselves says they are not appropriate for production, only for development. Security issues, load balancing, etc., are definitely part of it... plus, deploying Apache on Windows is just a nightmare.

Use LAMP. Alternatively, use IIS... if you're going to deploy a Windows production server (don't), use IIS.

Comment: Apparently I stand corrected... I thought the installation process included a disclaimer to that effect. Apparently I am confusing WampServer2 with some other WAMP package (EasyPHP perhaps?)

Comment: I found that deploying Apache on Windows was actually straightforward and very easy.

Answer (score 0):

LAMP is more stable, but i have wamp running intranet-sites succesfully in two organisations with over a 1000 users.

Comment: In what ways is WampServer unstable?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not, but why use Apache on Windows when you can quite easily install PHP on IIS?

Answer (score 0):

I love how the only guy who answered the actual question by paying attention to the fact that the OP was asking about the all in one product that is WampServer has a -1 rating. To reiterate what he said though, yes it would be a bad idea to use it in a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using WAMP over Windows Server 2003 as a production server for an Intranet. accesing MySQL and SQL Server toghether.
We are not too many users, but I had no problem so far.
Easy configuration, easy maintenance, posibility to autenticate domain users in Apache... 
Perhaps with heavy load environments it's not so good, but for me is the perfect sollution by now.

Answer (score 0):

YES, it can be used in production under condition that you install the secure WAMP distro. And yes it can run on Internet and not just intranet.

Here is a link to a secure WAMP for production where you can customize the security level and other settings to suit production environment.

http://securewamp.org/en/

Windows and WAMP can be successfully used in production even on high traffic websites however you will need to make changes and switch from mod_php to FCGID.

Answer (score -2):

Why not just use LAMP?  PHP code is portable.  I used WAMP for development, LAMP for production.

WAMP would probably work for production, but why not just use LAMP?